# Is there any similar idiom/proverb to Japanese proverb -Gesu no kanguri

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

There is a saying 下衆の勘繰り(Gesu no kanguri) in Japanese.

"Gesu" means a person who is mean, lowly, or base in his/her heart.
"Kanguri" means interpreting falsely someone's intention as bad.

A translation of this saying can be:
*A mean person often interprets an innocent person's intention as bad.*"

Is there a similar saying in English?
If not, what would you say to such a person?

Comment: Do you want an expression that you could *politely* say *to* such a person?  *Impolitely* say *to* such a person?  Or (in a conversation with other people) say *about* such a person?

Comment: @Jasper Various expressions are welcome.

Comment: I am not sure about a phrase, but you might describe such a person as *paranoid* or *a distrustful lowlife*. Or "a useless person trusts no one" (made this up but something like this, maybe).

Comment: Phrases I've heard is "You'll find what you are looking for" and "you'll see what you want to see."

Answer (score 2):

> "Suspicion always haunts the guilty mind" (Shakespeare, Henry VI, Part III, [Act 5 Scene 6](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=henry6p3&Act=5&Scene=6&Scope=scene))

The original sense of the quote in the play is not exactly equal to the sense of the Japanese proverb, but when abridged, it might fit. Language is flexible.

---

In the original text, the full sentence is used to indicate that "a guilty person is always afraid of retribution":

> **Henry VI.**
>   So flies the reckless shepherd from the wolf;
>   So first the harmless sheep doth yield his fleece
>   And next his throat unto the butcher's knife.
>   What scene of death hath Roscius now to act?
>
> **Richard III (Duke of Gloucester).**
>   Suspicion always haunts the guilty mind;
>   The thief doth fear each bush an officer.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term [psychological projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection) sounds similar. You might say, "You are just projecting your own intentions on him."